# Como separar dos veces el If else para generar

Tags: java

*Quiero saber como separo para que muestre el cuadro de dialogo uno por si apruebo.*

Otro cuadro a ver si es nota 10, 9 u 8.

```
do {
    if (suma >= 0 && prom <= 7.99)
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Observacion: Pierde");
    else if (suma >= 8 && prom <= 13.99)
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Observacion: Supletorio");
    else if (suma >= 14 && prom <= 20)
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Observacion: Aprobado");

    //SEGUNDO CUADRO
    //Aqui que tengo que separar para que me muestre otro cuadro
    else if (prom >= 8 && prom < 8.99)
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "nota 8");
    else if (prom >= 9 && prom < 9.99)
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "nota9");
    else if (prom >= 10 && prom <= 10) {
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Nota10");
    }
} while (prom < 0);
```

Comment: Simplemente quita el "else" de la línea "else if( prom >= 8 && prom < 8.99) ". Quedaría así "if( prom >= 8 && prom < 8.99) ".

Comment: Exactamente como te ha comentado Iñigo. Si pones else if, si se cumple un if, no entrara en el else, entonces para que se miren los dos tiene que poner if en ves de else if, asi aunque se cumpla una, comprobara el otro if independientemente.

Comment: Gracias sabe como hago para que aprezca en el mismo cuadro de dialogo?? no en diferentes cuadros

Answer (score 0):

Hay dos posibles soluciones a tu problema:

La primera es *desconectar* los `if`. Por ahora, tienes una *cadena* de `if`'s, en el que el siguiente se evalúa solo si la condición del anterior ha dado `false` como resultado. Otra forma de escribirlo en la que se vería un poco más claro es:

```
if (condicion1)
  accionCondicion1();
else
  if (condicion2)
    accionCondicion2();
  else
    if (condicion3)
      accionCondicion3();
    else
      // y así hasta el infinito
```

Dado que tu quieres *romper* en un punto, para hacer una condición independiente de la otra, basta con quitar el `else`:

```
do {
    if (suma >= 0 && prom <= 7.99)
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Observacion: Pierde");
    else if (suma >= 8 && prom <= 13.99)
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Observacion: Supletorio");
    else if (suma >= 14 && prom <= 20)
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Observacion: Aprobado");

    //SEGUNDO CUADRO
    //Aqui que tengo que separar para que me muestre otro cuadro
    //aquí ya no hay else, pues esto es independiente de lo anterior.
    if (prom >= 8 && prom < 8.99)
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "nota 8");
    else if (prom >= 9 && prom < 9.99)
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "nota9");
    else if (prom >= 10 && prom <= 10) {
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Nota10");
    }
} while (prom < 0);
```

Otra posible solución es *anidar* los if, para que el segundo grupo se evalúe solo cuando hay realmente posibilidades de que de `true` en alguna condición:

```
do {
    if (suma >= 0 && prom <= 7.99)
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Observacion: Pierde");
    else if (suma >= 8 && prom <= 13.99) {
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Observacion: Supletorio");
        if (prom >= 8 && prom < 8.99)
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "nota 8");
        else if (prom >= 9 && prom < 9.99)
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "nota9");
        else if (prom >= 10 && prom <= 10) {
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Nota10");
        }
    }
    else if (suma >= 14 && prom <= 20)
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Observacion: Aprobado");

} while (prom < 0);
```